# How to remove BSSID from wpa_cli blacklist?

Tags: wireless, wpa-supplicant

I've searched everywhere and couldn't find a manual that would mention the blacklist command let alone how to remove an AP from the blacklist.

Answer (score 1):

> blacklist clear

Source: a very useful yet surprisingly obscure list of wpa_cli commands. http://hackerj.tistory.com/34

Comment: Archive link just in case: http://archive.is/5ogKP